# Bug in large sparse CSR binary matrices multiplication result

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

This boggles my mind, is this a known bug or am I missing something? If a bug is there a way to circumvent it?

---

Suppose I have a relatively small binary (0/1) n x q `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`, as in:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def get_dummies(vec, vec_max):
    vec_size = vec.size
    Z = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(vec_size), (np.arange(vec_size), vec)), shape=(vec_size, vec_max), dtype=np.uint8)
    return Z

q = 100
ns = np.round(np.random.random(q)*100).astype(np.int16)
Z_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(q), ns)
Z = get_dummies(Z_idx, q)
Z
```

```
<5171x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.uint8'>'
    with 5171 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Here `Z` is a standard dummy variables matrix, with n=5171 observations and q=100 variables:

```py
Z[:5, :5].toarray()
```

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

E.g., if the first 5 variables have...

```py
ns[:5]
```

```
array([21, 22, 37, 24, 99], dtype=int16)
```

frequencies, we would also see this in `Z`'s column sums:

```py
Z[:, :5].sum(axis=0)
```

```
matrix([[21, 22, 37, 24, 99]], dtype=uint64)
```

Now, as expected, if I multiply `Z.T @ Z` I should get a q x q diagonal matrix, on the diagonal the frequencies of the q variables:

```py
print((Z.T @ Z).shape)
print((Z.T @ Z)[:5, :5].toarray()
```

```
(100, 100)
[[21  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0 22  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 37  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 24  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 99]]
```

**Now for the bug**: If n is really large (for me it happens around n = 100K already):

```py
q = 1000
ns = np.round(np.random.random(q)*1000).astype(np.int16)
Z_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(q), ns)
Z = get_dummies(Z_idx, q)
Z
```

```
<495509x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.uint8'>'
    with 495509 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The frequencies are large, the sum of `Z`'s columns is as expected:

```py
print(ns[:5])
Z[:, :5].sum(axis=0)
```

```
array([485, 756, 380,  87, 454], dtype=int16)
matrix([[485, 756, 380,  87, 454]], dtype=uint64)
```

But the `Z.T @ Z` is messed up! In the sense that I'm not getting the right frequencies on the diagonal:

```py
print((Z.T @ Z).shape)
print((Z.T @ Z)[:5, :5].toarray())
```

```
(1000, 1000)
[[229   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 244   0   0   0]
 [  0   0 124   0   0]
 [  0   0   0  87   0]
 [  0   0   0   0 198]]
```

Amazingly, there is some relation to the true frequencies:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(ns, (Z.T @ Z).diagonal())
plt.xlabel('real frequencies')
plt.ylabel('values on ZZ diagonal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

What is going on?

I'm using standard colab:

```py
import scipy as sc

print(np.__version__)
print(sc.__version__)
```

```
1.25.2
1.11.4
```

PS: Obviously if I wanted just `Z.T @ Z`'s output matrix there are easier ways to get it, this is a very simplified reduced problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `uint8` in `get_dummies`

```py
print(Z.dtype, (Z.T @ Z)[:5, :5].dtype)
# uint8,  uint8
```

So the result is overflowing. The pattern is because the result is the true result modulo 256. If you change the dtype to `uint16`, the problem disappears.

The fact that `sum` increases the precision of the dtype is a bit surprising, but it is [documented](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.sum.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.sum) and consistent with what NumPy `sum` does.